# Inherited Stock

Tags: united-states, taxes

I inherited some Walmart stock.  I assume I only pay tax when I sell.  I was debating on selling some of it to reinvest in a stock that may pay higher dividend.  I work part time self employed and draw SS.  How much tax would I pay on what I sold-say $30,000 to then reinvest in another stock?  It may be a disadvantage considering cost of tax versus gain in a higher dividend.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing what country you live in, what State, if in the US, what is your income, and how much the stock was worth when you inherited it. I suggest asking your tax adviser what would be the tax effect, since it is highly individual. Also, we try not to give any "investment advice" here as it also is very individual. You can, instead, ask what would be the advantages and disadvantages of owning a dividend paying stock versus not paying for a retiree.

Answer (score 4):

Since you reference SS, I surmise you are in the US. 
Stock you inherit gets a stepped up basis when it's inherited. (so long as it was not contained within a tax deffered retirement account.)
When you sell, the new basis is taken from that day you inherited it. It should be minimal compared to your desire to diversify.